# What is the IPv6 equivalent of 192.168.xxx.xxx?

Tags: internet, ip, ipv6, intranet

I have a server which responds differently to requests from the general internet as opposed to the intranet. For IPv4 I can simply check if the address begins with `192.168`. *This works for my needs.* What is the equivalent for IPv6?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all "intranet" is not limited to `192.168`. There are *3* private networks defined in *RFC-1918*: `10.0.0.0/8`, `172.16.0.0/12` and `192.168.0.0/16`.

In IPv6, it is called a *Unique local address*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_local_address and covered in *RFC-4193* -- all addresses matching `FC00::/7`. Basically, you should be able to search for IPv6 addresses starting with `fc` or `fd`.

Comment: For those who are curious, the RFCs in question can be found at [RFC 1918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918) and [RFC 4193](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4193) respectively. See also [RFC 6761](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761) for reserved DNS zones ("domain names").

Comment: Also, it's worth keeping in mind that RFC 4193 mandates bit 8 of the IPv6 address to be set to 1 (called the "L" bit). Thus, only addresses falling into FD00::/8 are defined by RFC 4193, although it allows for extending into FC00::/8 in the future by allowing for later defining behavior where the L bit is set to 0 instead of 1. See [RFC 4193 section 3.1, *Format*](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4193#section-3.1).

Answer (score 0):

The “intranet” is your local subnet, ie. `your servers address/64`. IPv6 RFCs strongly discourage networks smaller than `/64`, so it’s unlikely you’ll encounter any.

While there are link-local addresses, they aren’t really relevant here, because you wouldn’t use them.

An additional ULA network might be an option, although it poses additional management overhead.